# Feynman-Kac formula for elliptic equation in whole space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, stochastic-processes

I can find the Feynman-Kac formula for boundary value problem of  elliptic equation and for Cauchy problem of parabolic equation. Is there any reference about the elliptic equation in whole space? In particular, I am looking for Feynman-Kac formula of
$$ a(x)u''(x)+b(x)u'(x)+c(x)u(x)=f(x)$$
in $\mathbb{R}$ for regular enough coefficients.

Comment: What are your boundary conditions? Is it a Cauchy problem?

Comment: There is no boundary value, it is a problem on the whole space.

Comment: The proof of the Feinmann Kac formula relies on the existence of an a.e. finite exit time from the boundary. Moreover even in 1D you need at least initial condition for a ODE to admit a unique solution. If you want to apply the Feinmann-Kac formula you need to know the value of the function on the boundary of your domain

Comment: In this case, I am concerning the problem on $\mathbb{R}$. Shall I put some decay, like $u(x)\to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ for the equation?

Comment: If you look at the F.K. formula there is also the term given by the exit time of the Brownian from the domain. Maybe it is possible by considering $T= \infty$ in the usual formula (e.g. shown [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.00144.pdf) ), but I'm not sure that works, as the proof I have of F.K heavily rely on exit time to be finite a.s.

Answer (score 0):

In Shreve-Karatzas pg.365, they study the Feynman Kac formula for continuous and linear growth coefficients for general Elliptic operator and the Dirichlet problem.

[image]

[image]